# Why is 'have' not 'is' in "Why have a chapter on dictionaries in a book on syntax?"?

Tags: grammar, meaning

From Jim Miller. (2002). An Introduction to English Syntax. p.47.

> Why have a chapter on dictionaries in a book on syntax?

According to my analysis,the declarative version is 'a chapter on dictionaries is in a book on syntax'.

And the interrogative version should be 'Why is a chapter on dictionaries in a book on syntax'.So I can not figure out why 'have' is used here.

Comment: **have** can *have* as one of its many meanings **to include** or **to put** or **to cause to be in a certain place or in a certain arrangement**.  *Why have raisins in an oatmeal cookie? Why have that book in the reference section of the library? Why have us stand near the window?* Your example is a rhetorical question. Your declarative version is more of a paraphrase than an inverted restatement in the declarative: *a book on syntax has a chapter on dictionaries*, or  *[somebody] has a chapter on dictionaries in a book on syntax*

Comment: It's very common to omit the subject in why questions when it's generic or unimportant. "Why go to the beach if it's raining?" "Why worry about that?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s an idiom, and in this example it’s equivalent to “Why include…?” Essentially the same as “Why would one want to have…?” Another consideration that makes *have* fit is that books **have** chapters.

It’s also something like, say, “Why have a grand piano in your kitchen?” Or a less unusual question like “Why have a cheese sandwich when you could have filet mignon?”